# React App does not update context but all children do

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to understand react better so I created a sandbox example to play with. I basically have this structure App->Child->Grandchild. I created my context then wrapped App in the provider, then used the context in each component. When I set the context in the child, the child and the grandchild get updated and the context looks different from the App. If I set the context in the grandchild, neither the child or App get updated. Here is what the context looks like in the child and grandchild:

```
  {convo: "A happy family is but an earlier heaven...", speak: ƒ speak()}
```

But in App I just get a string back, Not an object:

```
    IN CONTEXT: this works for direct children of the provider
```

My console.log looks like this:

```
 const text = useContext(ConvoContext);
 console.log("child:", text);
```

So it appears when context is set it only works for the children where it is set at?

Here is my code sandbox I've been playing with:

https://codesandbox.io/s/context-example-ecs92?file=/src/App.js:0-774

Comment: your context provider should be the Parent of all your child components and you should do every update inside the provider itself. so here you are trying to update context state outside of it

Comment: But I thought the whole point of context was that I could call its setState function from anywhere and all components getting that state would be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ContextProvider` always should be the highest parent of all `Components` and you just can update its state inside children of the `Context`.

```js
export CustomContext = React.createContext()

const CustomContextProvider = (props) => {
  let [convo, setConvo] = useState("For all children")

  return (
   <CustomContext.Provider value={{convo, setConvo /* rest of methods and states */}}>
     {props.children}
   </CustomContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

If you need your `App` component to be the first child of your `Context` you should change to something like this.

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(CustomContext);
  /* update hooks for context changes and local changes are going here */
  return <Child></Child>
}
```

At the last, you would wrap your app inside the `context` provider.

```js
export const AppWithContexProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <CustomContextProvider>
     <App />
    </CustomContextProvider>
  )
}
```

If you have another `Context` that is updating due to your last `CustomContext` you should add it inside that.

```js
export const AnotherContext = createContext()
export AnotherCustomContextProvider = (props) => {
   const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  /* also use a parnet context */
  let [parentState, setParentState] = useContext(CustomContext)
 return (
   <AnotherCustomContextProvider.Provider value={{setState}}>
     {props.children}
   </AnotherCustomContextProvider.Provider>
 )
}
```

Again add your child `context` and so on.

```js
export const AppWithContexProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <CustomContextProvider>
     /* this one can update convo value */
     <AnotherCustomContextProvider>
      <App />
     </AnotherCustomContextProvider>
    </CustomContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, moving my provider to index instead of App helped. I also used an empty dependency array in the grandchild and now it all works!

Comment: your welcome, great work!!